# Android: Popup Window: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: android, arraylist, popupwindow

I would like to add a popup window when the user press the category button. The window will show the list of category available. The related code for the popup window is as follows:

### `onCreate`:

```
    //popup choices
    localArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    localArrayList.add("action 1");     //0
    localArrayList.add("action 2");     //1
    localArrayList.add("action 3");     //2
    localArrayList.add("action 4");         //3
    localArrayList.add("action 5");     //4
    popUpContents = new String[localArrayList.size()];
    localArrayList.toArray(popUpContents);
    popupWindowDogs = ppopupWindowDogs();
```

### actions for pressing the button

```
public void onClickBtn_action(View v) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.btn_category:         
            popupWindowDogs.showAsDropDown(v, -5, Constants.SCREEN_H / 15); break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

### The popup window:

```
public PopupWindow ppopupWindowDogs() 
    {
        final PopupWindow localPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);                                               
        lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomArrayAdapter_POP(DB_Ex_ListActivity.this));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
              {
                  if (position == 0) 
                    {

                    } 

                    localPopupWindow.dismiss();
              }
        });

        localPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        localPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        localPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        localPopupWindow.setWidth(Constants.SCREEN_W / 2);
        localPopupWindow.setHeight(Constants.SCREEN_H );
        localPopupWindow.setContentView(lv);
        return localPopupWindow;
    }

    private class MyCustomArrayAdapter_POP extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;  
        private Context mContext = null;  
        public MyCustomArrayAdapter_POP(Context context) 
        {  
            mContext = context;  
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);  
        }  

        public int getCount() 
        {
            return localArrayList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) 
        {
            return localArrayList.get(arg0);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            }
            TextView lv_item_text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_item_text);
            lv_item_text.setText(category_list.get(position));
            }
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams((int)(Constants.SCREEN_W/2), (int)(Constants.SCREEN_W/7)));
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

### Question:

The popup does not show up when the button is pressed.
The Logcat reports

`Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`

Comment: Had the same issue. [This answer][1] worked for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227508

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code below your call to showAsDropDown

```
   popupWindowDogs.update(v,200,300 );
```

Adjust the 200 and 300 as per the width and height of the pop up.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  if (position == 0) 
                    {

                    } else{

                          localPopupWindow.dismiss();
                       }
              }
        });
```

put your **localPopupWindow.dismiss()** call in else, as when the if condition is failing , it will execute the next line which is localPopWindow.dimiss()